# Cuban US resident traveling from Canada to Cuba and back

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada, cuba, us-residents

I am a Cuban with a US resident card and I'm traveling from Canada to Cuba and I was wondering if I need a Canadian visa to come back from Cuba to get into Canada if I'm using a Cuban passport.

Comment: What did you need to enter Canada in the first place?

Comment: Im getting the plane in canada to go to cuba

Comment: that's not my question. Unless you were born in Canada, you got in somehow, yes? Did you use your Cuban passport? Did you need a visa?

Comment: Im cuban i live in the united states near the canadian border..im taking a plane from canada to cuba. Do i need a canadian visa when i come back from cuba to canada if i use my cuban passport

Comment: you are just repeating what is in your question. I don't understand why you are concerned about going from Cuba to Canada but don't appear concerned about the first step, going from the US to Canada. If you expect them to easily let you in that time, at the start of your trip, why do you expect any issues the second time you enter Canada, after having been in Cuba? Either you're admissible to Canada or you're not, and entering from the US is not that different from entering from Cuba.

Comment: #KateGregory he is triying to travel trough canada because where they live near to the Canadian border non exist diretc flight to cuba, he have to go to miami to flight to Cuba, should be less expesive go to canada and flight to cuba, I think. miami- habana flights start at 430 usd + where they live to Miami

Answer (score 8):

> **I have U.S. residency (Green Card). Do I need a visa to visit Canada
>   or can I use my Green Card?**
>
> As a U.S. Green Card holder, you do not need a temporary resident visa
>   to travel to Canada. At the Canadian border, you will need to present
>   your valid passport and Green Card.

[Citizenship and Immigration Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?q=593&t=16)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a green card, [you don't need a passport or visa to get into Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=593&top=16).

> When travelling by land or sea directly from the U.S., you will only need to provide proof of your U.S. lawful permanent resident status (such as your Green Card).